# What field does the data have on new Firebase cloud functions for v1.0?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Here is the code for non HTTP on newest firebase cloud function SDK

```
exports.dbWrite = functions.database.ref('/pat/with/{id}').onWrite((data, context) => {    
const authVar = context.auth; 
const authType = context.authType;
const pathId = context.params.id; 
const eventId = context.eventId; 
const timestamp = context.timestamp;
const eventType = context.eventType; 
const resource = context.resource;

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access the fields like this:

```
exports.dbWrite = functions.database.ref('/path').onWrite((data, context) => {
  const beforeData = data.before.val(); // data before the write
  const afterData = data.after.val(); // data after the write
});
```

As stated in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#event_parameter_split_into_data_and_context ("Event data now a DataSnapshot")

Comment: On the first section of the link yes, but you have to scroll down to the section "Event data now a DataSnapshot" which I referenced in my answer.

Comment: I have access the way it is on the docs but am getting a null. @Leonardo G

Comment: could you please share/update that code snippet @AllyMakongo? exactly as you are using it

Comment: I already fixed it. The issue was how to extract the data from json tree using the newest sdk.

Comment: Yep, the docs on the link tell you the changes on the v1 of cloud functions. Glad you fixed it!